# Does solrj support indexing nested documents with _nest_path_ field?

Tags: solr, solrj

We using Solr 8 and solrj client library to indexing nested documents. After indexing the index contains all docs but doesn't automatically fill the _nest_path_ field. The *root* field was properly field. What can be the reason for the missing _nest_path_ field?

The expected result should be the automatically filled field _nest_path_.